# file handling via post request in asp & c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to process a file coming from a post request.
The file looks like this:
first line: text1
second line: empty line
third line: text2
an example:

"
asdasdasd1

asdasdasd2
"

so far i processed the file like this:

byte[] data = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes);

String processedfile = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

But this was i lose the page breaks and the whole string becomes 1 line instead of 3.

How can i process the resquest where at the end i can keep the page breaks?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: When you say the file is coming in via the request - is it just some text in the post body - or is it uploaded using the `<input type="file" />` html control?  Oh and hey, two 'Zoltans' on the same web page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using an HTML upload control on the page (which would preserve the entire file without issue) - my guess is that the significant whitespace in your 'file', isn't percent-encoded (or URL encoded: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and so is getting dropped.

Your client needs to URL encode the file contents otherwise stuff like spaces, tabs, etc will most likely be lost.

Comment: No, it's not percent encoded. However i hope i could get my line breaks back :(
I recieve the file using curl

Comment: only line breaks were lost. The tabs and spaces stayed.

Comment: Ah okay - they will probably be interpreted as spaces by the web server.  They ideally need to be encoded as %0A or %0D by the agent making the request.  It's possible that cUrl is actually deciding to ignore them when it makes the request.